# How to get object keys after a BucketDeployment using CDK

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk, bucket

Hi have a CDK package where I am using the `BucketDeployment` construct to prefill my bucket with some files. How do I get the object keys of these files that I just uploaded? I want to use one of those object keys(filename) in my Cloudfront distribution and set it as a `defaultRootObject`. The filename will have a hash attached to it and will be different everytime, so I cannot hardcode it anywhere.

filename pattern: `something-[id].js`

Comment: A BucketDeployment bundles your files locally.  How is your hash id calculated?

Comment: hash id depends on the content of the file and is generated by webpack

Comment: this can be achieved by creating a custom resource https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/custom-resources-readme.html. However, I would try to change the deployment process so that it does not require update cloudfront distribution every time.